# Encontrar alunos sem turma - Python / Excel

Tags: python, banco-de-dados, python-3.x, microsoft-excel, recursão

Tenho uma planilha em Excel com todos os meus alunos e suas respectivas séries (5ª a 9ª).

Preciso achar todos os meus alunos que não estejam em nenhuma turma. Pelo filtro do Excel eu consigo fazer, mas tenho quase 5 mil alunos cadastrados e gostaria de encontrar uma forma mais automática e rápida de fazer esse trabalho.

Como estou começando a aprender Python, gostaria que a ajuda viesse nessa linguagem se possível.

Tentei usar um `for` loop mas acho que eu não fiz direito, porque ele só traz o primeiro nome e a primeira série do aluno (quase como um `PROCV` do Excel).

[image: Exemplo]

Na imagem de exemplo, a aluna Gabriela seria uma das alunas que eu teria de filtrar, pois ela já não está em nenhuma turma de nenhuma série. Os demais já concluíram algumas séries e/ou faltam concluir outras, então em algum momento esses alunos tem sua matrícula vigente.

Desde já, agradeço a ajuda de todos! ;)

--

Até aqui, escrevi o seguinte código:

```
aluno = ["Pedro", "Gabriela", "Aluisio", "Deborah"]
matricula = ["Vigente", "Sem turma"]

for n in aluno:
    if matricula == "Vigente":
        print(f"Curso de {aluno} em andamento.")
    else
        print(f"Curso de {aluno} concluído.")
```

Comment: Publique o código em Python que você já escreveu para que possamos ajudar-lhe com suas dificuldades.

Comment: Obrigado, Augusto! Acabei de editar a postagem original com o código que eu escrevi até aqui.

Comment: Esse código não é capaz de manipular dados no Excel. No minimo teria que usar uma das bibliotecas listadas nessa [página](http://www.python-excel.org/). Ou se estiver usando Ironpython teria que ter a linha  `import clr clr.AddReference("Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Além de importar a planilha para uma estrutura em python, de preferencia um `DataFrame`, como sugere o Isaque em sua resposta, é preciso, também, iterar os dados para extrair somente os "alunos sem turma". Uma forma de fazer isso:

```
import pandas as pd

# Importando a planilha para um pandas DataFrame
df = pd.read_excel('plan1.xls', sheet_name='Sheet1')

# Organizando os dados para o contexto
data = {}
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    if list(row)[0] not in data:
        data[list(row)[0]] = [list(row)[2]]
    else:
        data[list(row)[0]].append(list(row)[2]) 

# Selecionando os alunos "sem turma"
sem_turma = [aluno for aluno in data if 'Vigente' not in data[aluno]]

print(sem_turma)
```

Saida:

```
['Gabriela']
```

> Editada
>   Uma outra forma mais compacta de conseguir o mesmo resultado:

```
import pandas as pd
# Importando a planilha para um pandas DataFrame
df = pd.read_excel('plan1.xls', sheet_name='Sheet1')

# Selecionando os nomes dos alunos em um set
alunos = set(list(df['Aluno']))

# Selecionando os alunos "vigentes" em um set
vigentes = set(df.loc[df['Matricula'] == "Vigente"]['Aluno'])

# Selecionando os "sem turma"
print(alunos-vigentes)
```

Saída:

```
{'Gabriela'}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Importar a planilha

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    #importar biblioteca
    import pandas as pd
    #importar arquivo excel 
    dados = pd.read_excel('dados.xlsx', sheet_name='Planilha1')
    #filtro
    df1 = dados.loc[dados['Matricula'] == "Vigente"]
    print(df1)
```

```
      Aluno  Serie Matricula
2     Pedro      7   Vigente
11  Aluisio      6   Vigente
15  Deborah      5   Vigente
```